# graphviz fill gap between two borders (peripheries)

Tags: border, graphviz

```
digraph {
graph[bgcolor="gold1:dodgerblue"]
node[shape=box;style="filled";];
edge[color="#000080";arrowhead="open";];

A [peripheries=2;color="blue:green:blue";fillcolor="#ddffff";];
B [fillcolor="#ddffff";];
A->B
}
```

Outputs the first picture. How to fill the gap and get the second picture?

[image: actual]
[image: wanted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact solution is still not found but [HTML-Like Labels](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) give a visually equivalent workaround. Though the code is pretty verbose it suites for my case.

```
digraph {
graph[imagepath=".";];
graph[layout=dot;rankdir=LR;];
node[shape=box;style="filled";];
node[shape=box;style="filled";penwidth="1";width=0;height=0;margin="0.05,0.05"];
edge[color="#000080";arrowhead="open";];

A [fillcolor="yellow";label=< <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bgcolor="#ffddff">
<tr><td cellpadding="5" border="0">Marked node</td></tr>
</table> >;];

B [fillcolor="#ddffff";label="Ordinary node";];

A->B
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No solution yet. Found an alternative way to highlight the node:

```
digraph {
graph[imagepath=".";];
graph[layout=dot;rankdir=LR;];
node[shape=box;style="filled";];
node[shape=box;style="filled";penwidth="0.5";width=0;height=0;margin="0.05,0.05"];
edge[color="#000080";arrowhead="open";];

A [fillcolor="#ffddff";label="Marked node";image="rect2681.png";imagepos="tl";margin="0.2,0.05"];
B [fillcolor="#ddffff";label="Ordinary node";];
A->B
}
```

[image: alternative]

Works in `graphviz-2.44.1`. In `graphviz-2.38` (and in `graphviz-2.40.1` as I could check in Ubuntu) the image is always positioned in the center, i.e. `imagepos` doesn't work.

Also see [the documentation](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:imagepos).

**UPDATE**

Some problems found with `graphviz-2.44.1` so need to get back to `graphviz-2.38` and using [HTML-Like Labels](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html):

```
digraph {
graph[imagepath=".";];
graph[layout=dot;rankdir=LR;];
node[shape=box;style="filled";];
node[shape=box;style="filled";penwidth="0.5";width=0;height=0;margin="0.05,0.05"];
edge[color="#000080";arrowhead="open";];

A [fillcolor="#ffddff";label=< <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td><img src="circle_mark.png"/></td>
<td cellpadding="5">Marked node</td></tr>
</table> >; margin="0.04,0"];
B [fillcolor="#ddffff";label="Ordinary node";];
A->B
}
```

[image]